# SharePoint - Adding Multiple Arguments With Date Validation

Tags: validation, date, sharepoint-2013

Currently I'm using an argument that doesn't allow new items older than today's date. I would like to change this to have either an and/or argument to only allow dates of today and/or less than three days from today.

Example being; if today is 2/9, allow them to add any dates from 2/9-2/12. Otherwise the validation will give an error for "Out of Range".

Currently I'm using the below code:

```
=[Appt Time]>TODAY()
```

I've tried using this as well, but the code is not working. I assume it's due to formatting,  or my argument is just totally wrong:

```
=AND(TODAY()>[Appt Time], [Appt Time]<TODAY()+3)
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've cracked it. Wrong formula entered into the validation field: `=AND([Appt Time]>TODAY(),[Appt Time]<TODAY()+4)`